# Ban IPs from text file using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ip, text-files, block

I read and understand how to block an ip using htaccess:

```
order deny,allow
deny from 111.222.33.44
deny from 55.66.77.88
...
allow from all
```

But my list of black IPs includes thousands of IPs.
I save all IPs to a **blacklist.txt** file.

Can I use htaccess to call **blacklist.txt** and block all IPs which are stored in this file? If so, how?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try using variations of [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap). You'll need access to the server/vhost config because that directive only works there. You can then use the map inside htaccess files.

Say your **blacklist.txt** file looks like this:

```
111.222.33.44  deny
55.66.77.88    deny
192.168.0.1    allow
```

You can define the map like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap access txt:/path/to/blacklist.txt
```

Then in your htaccess, you can invoke the map:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond ${access:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} deny [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

The condition invokes the map and checks if the remote address maps to the word "deny", and if so, the rewrite rule outright forbids access.

If your **blacklist.txt** is only a list of IPs, and you don't want to add a "deny" after each one, you'll need to invoke a program map type and write a script, something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    read INPUT
    MATCH=`grep $INPUT /path/to/blacklist.txt`
    if [ -z "$MATCH"  ]; then
        echo "allow"
    else
        echo "deny"
    fi
done
```

which infinite loops read input and greps the **blacklist.txt** file. If the IP is in the file, output a "deny", otherwise it outputs a "allow". Then you'd create the map like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap access prg:/path/to/blacklist.txt
```

And the rewrite rule to check against the map would be no different.