# What's the best way to restrict IP address?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Suppose I wanted to ban a specific IP address from accessing the whole domain name *(+ all included subdomains)*. At first I began with the following snippet to add the following lines to the .htaccess file:

```
$info = 'Order Deny,Allow
Deny from' . IPtoBlock();

if (getIP()){
    $htaccess = fopen('.htaccess', 'r+');
    fwrite($htaccess, $info);
    fclose($htaccess);
}
```

But is it more relevant to redirect the user to something else? After all, he is still capable of making a request towards the server despite the immediate redirect.

```
$deny = array('192.168.1.0', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2');
if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $deny)) {
   header("location: http://www.google.com/");
}
```

or simply kill the page?

```
$deny = array('192.168.1.0', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2');
if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $deny)) {
   die('Access restricted');
}
```

What is the best approach towards this issue?

Comment: don't do it at the php level. do it at least at the webserver level. or better yet, at the firewall/router level. if you don't want someone to access your stuff, don't let them even get in the front door.

Comment: I'd stick with the .htaccess. Then you can design a custom 403 page, with `ErrorDocument 403 forbidden.html`. But that if you want to just show them an error, if they're dangerous enough to ban from the entire website, maybe they're dangerous enough to ban at the entire network level (udp, tcp, etc).

Comment: That makes sense but I'm not always the one in control of the server and I wanna make sure certain pages are not publicly available.

Comment: Certain pages, or `the whole domain name (+ all included subdomains)`? If the IPs you are banning are based off a list, and you're only banning them from specific pages, then you might want to try your PHP technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jour `.htaccess` :

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from 123.123.123.123
```

User with ip 123.123.123.123 will have a 403.

And if you want to redirect to a specific page, add :

```
ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden.php
```

Edit : For ban Ip from text file in htaccess, take a look here : [Ban IPs from text file using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008242/ban-ips-from-text-file-using-htaccess)

Comment: Does this mean that the `fwrite()` on .htaccess is a good idea? Since I want to make it dynamic and not add IPs manually.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008242/ban-ips-from-text-file-using-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htacces` File:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from xx.xx            // This will be your local IP address
Allow from yy.yy.yy.yy      // Your server IP address
```

Except from these scenario, no one can access your website.

Answer (score 0):

The best ist do block this attempt before it even reaches your webserver. That means blocking on a level like iptables (firewall; or if you can't do that and are using a load balancer, then block it there).