# Update .htaccess with current IP address

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic, ip, append, pipe

Excuse my ignorance, just getting to grips with CentOS bash properly.

What I'd like to do is have a .sh script that I can enter my current home IP address into, and run manually so it will update 3 or 4 .htaccess files on the web server.

How can I do this by updating just the IP in the .htaccess files? 
deny from all 
allow from my.current.home.IP

This way, when my Dynamic IP changes, I can quickly restore access to my private areas without going around to each file and manually editing them.

I'd rather not just pipe/append a new allow entry to the bottom of the file as I have no idea where the IP goes after me.

Can't see me being the first to want this so please feel free to post, thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008242/ban-ips-from-text-file-using-htaccess?rq=1

would this do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're only going to have a single Allow (and that's your IP) then you can probably run a single command:

```
sed -i -e 's/Allow [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]$/Allow 12.34.56.78/g' .htaccess
```

You can put that in a bash script if you want. `12.34.56.78` is your new IP and the `.htaccess` is the path (relative or absolute) to your htaccess file.