# programmatically add ip address to .htaccess file from mysql table and block user

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

Hi good programming friends of ours,
based on the subject of this question, I have searched the entire site for related questions on the subject. But I have not found something similarly to reading from a db table and parsing values to .htaccess file.

The quest is this:

If php records 3 failed login attempts from a particular ip address, .htaccess should be invoked to block access from that user.

This quest is available on this site.
But what is not available is the next lines below:

1) .htaccess should be invoked each time a person tries to access all the files only in this folder .
2) .htaccess should read a table mysql and compare the incoming ip with a list of ips in mysql table.
3) if there is a match, .htaccess should redirect the user to a free-entry location.

Note that, I can use php with mysql select statement to check this on the  file inside  folder.
But I do not want this scenario. I rather want to use .htaccess file.

Here, .htaccess file will not record ip address, but will only check whether such ip is already in the table.

For instance - the psudo-code below:

```
.htaccess file enabled = true
create a temporary variable ($ip) in .htaccess file
On user access to any .php pages in /test/ folder,
retrieve user's ip and temporarily store in $ip variable.

open connection on .php page
load login table having ip match as $ip.
if found then redirect
else continue to loading page
end if
close connection
end on
destroy the variable
```

please do not mind my psudo-code.... though it may look stupid and childish.
That's the concept but, I do not really know how to write to or read from .htaccess filee, nor what programming language is used on .htaccess programming.

Please any help will be appreiated...
Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you're a bit misguided on the use-case for `htaccess`

Comment: [dbd `RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#dbd)

Comment: Well, I hope you do know that an IP != a person irl. You should look at denyhosts or just do it in your application stack if it's only about failed login attempts.

Comment: If .htaccess were to do all of that, then there would be no need to write actual business logic in any of the web programming languages. Please study a bit more about `.htaccess` and its limitiations before posting such questions.

Comment: Why are you upset that I do not know what I asked? If you were a teacher, you will not have students.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008242/ban-ips-from-text-file-using-htaccess)

```
RewriteMap access txt:/path/to/blacklist.txt
```

you can use your php code to update the blacklist.txt It's much safer IMHO

Comment: I have seen the answer.... it is reading from a txt file.
 I have a problem reading from mysql db table.
 Secondly, in writing the .htaccess codes, RewriteMap ...etc, do I need to open the .htaccess file and write the code?
 What do I do here? Thanks.

Comment: You know, if a hacker uses a particular system to try generated passwords and usernames, on the 3rd attempt, his ip should be blocked. So, he has to keep trying more systems. Tell me, how many systems will he purchase to keep trying 3x of his generated codes to be able to get a hash password and username? Each username and password is hashed. So, it will take such a hacker a donkey year to be able to scale through. That is the idea behind trying to block ip address.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on a site, but it seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

```
<?php


// Get the IP address of the visitor so we can work with it later.
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// This is where we pull the file and location of the htaccess file. If it's in
// the same directory as this php file, just leave it as is.
$htaccess = '.htaccess';

// This pulls the current contents of your htaccess file so we can search it later.
$contents = file_get_contents($htaccess, TRUE) 
          OR exit('Unable to open .htaccess');

// Lets search the htaccess file to see if there is already a ban in place.
$exists = !stripos($contents, 'deny from ' . $ip . "\n") 
          OR exit('Already banned, nothing to do here.');

// Here we just pull some details we can use later.
$date   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$uri    = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ENT_QUOTES);
$agent  = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], ENT_QUOTES);
$agent  = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $agent);

// If you would like to be emailed everytime a ban happens, put your email
// INSIDE the quotes below. (e.g. 'my@email.com')
$email = '';

// This is where we can whitelist IP's so they can never be banned. Simply remove 
// the //  from the front of one of the example IP addresses below and add the 
// address you wish to whitelist. Make sure that you leave the single quotes (') 
// intact and the comma at the end. Adding a person to the whitelist AFTER they 
// have been banned will NOT remove them. You must open the htaccess file and 
// locate their ban by hand and remove it.
$whitelist = array(
  // '123.123.123.123',
  // '123.123.123.123',
  // '123.123.123.123',
);


// This section prevents people from being sent to this script by mistake
// via a link, image, or other referer source. If you don't want to check
// the referer, you can remove the following line. Make sure you also
// remove the ending } at the very end of this script.
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {

// This section will write the IP address to the htaccess file and in turn
// ban the address. It will however check the whitelist above to see if
// should be banned.
  if (in_array($ip, $whitelist)) {

    // User is in whitelist, print a message and end script.
    echo "Hello user! Because your IP address ({$ip}) is in our whitelist,
    you were not banned for attempting to visit this page. End of line.";

  } else {

    // User is NOT in whitelist - we need to ban em...
    $ban =  "\n# The IP below was banned on $date for trying to access {$uri}\n";
    $ban .= "# Agent: {$agent}\n";
    $ban .= "Deny from {$ip}\n";

    file_put_contents($htaccess, $ban, FILE_APPEND) 
          OR exit('Cannot append rule to .htaccess');

    // Send email if address is specified
    if (!empty($email)) {
      $message = "IP Address: {$ip}\n";
      $message .= "Date/Time: {$date}\n";
      $message .= "User Agent: {$agent}\n";
      $message .= "URL: {$uri}";

      mail($email, 'Website Auto Ban: ' . $ip, $message);
    }

    // Send 403 header to browser and print HTML page
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden', TRUE);
    echo '<html><head><title>Error 403 - Banned</title></head><body>
    <center><h1>Error 403 - Forbidden</h1>Hello user, you have been 
    banned from accessing our site. If you feel this ban was a mistake, 
    please contact the website administrator to have it removed.<br />
    <em>IP Address: '.$ip.'</em></center></body></html>';

  }

}
```

In .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch 403.shtml>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow From All
</FilesMatch>
```

[Source](http://kb.site5.com/security/how-to-automatically-block-someone-using-a-php-script/)

Comment: Hi guys, I appreciate your comments...but lets go further.
 I have already written a code to check for fail attempts and add the ip addresses to a mysql table. Now, I need to call out the IPs in the table and use .htaccess file to compare matching IPs. That's what I need to do. Please more comments... thank you!