# Apache "SetEnvIF" list of IP Addresses read from separate file?

Tags: .htaccess, file, file-read, ip-blocking, x-forwarded-for

I'm using Apache and `.htaccess` to **BLOCK** the IP Addresses, like this, as an example:

```
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "110.100.*.*" DenyIP
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "120.100.*.*" DenyIP
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "130.100.*.*" DenyIP
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "210.200.*.*" DenyIP
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "220.200.*.*" DenyIP
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "230.200.*.*" DenyIP
..
..
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=DenyIP
```

These are quite a lot actually, in the real file.

*( Please let's don't discuss about why i'm using such approach to block the IPs via Apache. There are many reasons behind. )*

Is there a way i can list the IP(s) down inside a `.txt` file, and then point to that file from `.htaccess`?

---

Something like this:

```
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For /var/www/html/ips.txt DenyIP
```

I would then be able to put the IP(s) simply line by line, in `ips.txt` file like this:

```
110.100.*.*
120.100.*.*
130.100.*.*
210.200.*.*
220.200.*.*
230.200.*.*
```

Because, like this is more easy (and possible) to automate the IP entries, into the `.txt` file.

---

Is this **even possible**? Or what is the proper approach for this please?

Thanks all :)

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible with `SetEnvIf`. You'll need to use [`RewriteMap`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13009206/1626250). This also gives you the flexibility of redirecting denied users somewhere else.

Comment: @MikeRockett Thank you. Can you give some examples, may be as in Answer, pls? :)

Comment: I gave you a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13009206/1626250) in my comment to an answer that already does what you need.