# RewriteMap with shell script

Tags: bash, mod-rewrite

Using the following SO question [Ban IPs from text file using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008242/ban-ips-from-text-file-using-htaccess)
I have implemented the same process but it is not working.

for testing purpose i have just added

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "deny"
```

and in my .htacess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond ${filterip:%{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR}} deny [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

In vhost

```
RewriteMap filterip prg:/path/filterip.sh
```

in my shell script file. but it doesn't seems to be working. can you please help me with this. what else is needed to execute shell scrip to be executed in rewrite map, even i have given executable permission to script but nothing.

Comment: Welcome. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and format your post properly.

Comment: you'll need to say something more than "not working". Look at rewrite trace.

But a rewrite map program should not exit after queried once, and you need to read STDIN even if you don't use it.  Loop over stdin.